# SSRS Parameter using a stored procedure with a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report that pulls data using a stored procedure. Two of the parameters on this report have default values stored (i.e. Role:Student, ID:Guest)

One of the parameters is a `dropdown` that is filled with a different stored procedure using the two parameters mentioned above. When I set the parameters for this new dataset to `@Role` and `@ID`, I get a `rsInvalidReportParameterDependancy` error. I have changed the order of the two parameters with no success. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question has been posted before. However, I did not realize that I had the same issue. The answer has to do with the parameters not being in the correct order. For instance, I had 6 parameters on the main report. Parameters 5 and 6 were hidden to the user. Parameter 3 contained a dropdown that was populated by a stored procedure that needed @Param5 and 6. Even though parameters 5 and 6 had default values, it would not work until I moved param5 and 6 before param3.

I changed the order of the parameters on the report's main stored procedure and then change the parameters order in the report. (I ended up doing this using a text editor.)

@param1
@param2
@param3
@param4
@param5
@param6

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have three parameters but you have only mentioned changing the order of two. In my head, I would think that Role and ID must come first in your list of Parameters. I'd start by sorting those to the top. Then you should be able to add in your third parameter, populated by the result of those two. Can you provide any more information of what you've tried or what doesn't work?